# call AS function from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, jquery-selectors, mxml

Using jquery,JS can we call a function in flex code.Below is that i have a button which calls a AS code.Can this be done if so how ?

```
 <script>
   function callas()
   {
    addBody();//call flex function        
   }
 </script>

 <input type="button" onclick="callas();" />
```

**FLEX code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">


<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.net.*;


public function addBody():void
{

  Alert.show("Got input from JS");

}
</mx:Script>


</mx:Application >
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

*Javascript*

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    document.getElementById(movieName).setAttribute("name", movieName);
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

function callas()
{
   // You need to know the ID of the object/embed tag; swfobject has an attribute for that. see http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#How_can_you_configure_your_Flash_content?
   var swfobjectID = 'myFlashObjectID'  
   //call flex function 
   getFlashMovie(swfobjectID).addBody();
}
```

*Actionscript / flex*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

//                "javascript function", flash function
ExternalInterface.addCallback("addBody", addBody);

public function addBody():void
{
  Alert.show("Got input from JS");
}
</mx:Script>

</mx:Application >
```

**sources:**
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#How_can_you_configure_your_Flash_content?

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize an Actionscript class named `ExternalInterface` to interact with Javascript.

So, if you'd like to call a Javascript function from Flex or Flash, then you should use something like this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("Javscriptfunction", parameters);
```

Should you want to call Actionscript from Javascript, try the following:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("javascriptfunc", flexfunc);

protected function flexfunc(result:String):void{
    trace(result);
}
```